# Acquire Gtk binaries for windows under linux

Tags: gtk, cross-compiling, gtkmm

I am currently trying to compile my Gtkmm program for windows using my linux system. This requires that I ship the Gtk binaries (in this case .dll's) with my program, since Gtk does not support static linking.

But I just dont know how to get them - the official Gtk download page ( https://www.gtk.org/download/windows.php ) just redirects to the MSYS2 project ( http://www.msys2.org/ ) that offers .EXE files **rage*!

I just dont know where I can download the right dll files that I need to include :/

I would appreciate any help with this.

Regards,

NiAypa

Answer (score 1):

The GTK+ project does not distribute binaries for any platform.

If you are cross-compiling from Linux to Windows, you will need to cross-compile all the dependencies yourself, and distribute them together. Various distributions, like Fedora, ship with cross-compiled dependencies that you can re-use for that purpose.

The MSYS2 project is for building applications and libraries on Windows, using a native toolchain.

I'd like to point out that cross-compiling is great if you want to do CI and testing, but if you want to distribute complex applications for Windows my suggestion would be to actually build them on Windows.

Comment: thanks for that reply it was very helpful because I didnt quite get I need to compile the dll myself actually :/